# Socket io outputting lots of connection failures on the console with react / node app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

This is my configuration

```js
const io = require("socket.io")(1100, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
  },
});
```

[image]

`cors` is installed.

What could be the problem?
What is the fix?

On the React side:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.current.connect();
    socket.current.on("refresh-restock", (sodaName) => {
      setUpdateMsg({
        success: true,
        msg: sodaName + " is now fully restocked",
      });
    });

    socket.current.on("update-admin-view", (msg) => {
      setUpdateMsg({
        success: true,
        msg: msg,
      });
    });
    return () => socket.current.disconnect();
  }, []);
```

On the socket server side:

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  socket.on("refresh-restock", (sodaName) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit("refresh-restock", sodaName);
  });

  socket.on("update-admin-view", (msg) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit("update-admin-view", msg);
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have the exact same version of socket.io on client and server?

Comment: yup, both are 4.5.1

Comment: How are you loading socket.io into the client?  Can you show relevant client-side code?

Comment: Why are there POST requests to your socket.io endpoint?  That doesn't make any sense.  There must be something  highly unusual in the client that is making POST requests.  The socket.io library on its own would not be making a POST request.

Comment: But there not POST request being made on the React side. It only calls the `on` method. Is the react side is only receiving data. The node side is `emitting`

Comment: Your screenshot shows multiple POST requests to the socket.io endpoint.  The question is where in your client is that coming from?  That's wrong.